# How can i use ruby on rails software snippet into my exisiting php project?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making a project in PHP, but I want the "Investor portal" which is the part of the same software to be build in Ruby. Can I make the project on Ruby for making a separate portal, but database is shared across the applications and everything is linked at the end.

Can someone please tell me is it possible to do so via API calls or how can I do that, efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done, but it's not considered a best (or even good) practice. You will be maintaining two distinct applications and - as they will share the same database - need to share business logic. Because PHP and Ruby are not interchangeable, you'll need to write all your business logic and validations twice *and* keep them in sync.

This is only the most obvious issue, but what about authentication? Sharing sessions? Hosting? Developers able and willing to develop in both PHP and Ruby?

Your question will get probably get down voted into oblivion because common sense dictated that you should use one programming language for one application (unless you're ready to step in to the hell that's called microservices).

Comment: Aha, i see your point. Please correct me if i am saying illogical "We have same auth but portals are different,for customers and investor,and hosting are same too." one portal is build on php and other one in ruby. Is my logic right? Thanks